# how to remove the \ character

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string with the following information:

```
\"[{\"CodRTA\":\"1\",\"MenssRTA\":\"messaje error\",\"Resp\":\"\"}]\"
```

and I need to delete the character `\` I'm trying to remove as follows, but the character is using the system and leaves close the line of code

```
NSString *filtered = [[[restConnection stringData] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSLog(@"filtrado: %@", filtered);
```

the error is

```
Expected ']' in this part : componentsSeparatedByString:@"\"]
```

Comment: What about not removing it. and parse the json. does it gave an error? I believe json parser will handle that.

Comment: Yes.. this is json formatted string. So why don'y you deserialize it with json.

Comment: I'm trying so using JSON: json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:string options:0 error:nil]; but don't work allway the result is null

Comment: If you delete the backslashes it will no longer be a legal character string literal.

Comment: So, when you use NSJSONSerialization and it fails, what is the `error` value??  Oh!!  I see - you're ignoring the `error` value.

Comment: I found the error and that the original string is @ "\" [{\ "CodRTA \": \ "1 \", \ "MessageRTA \": \ "information \", \ "Resp \": \ "\ "}] \" "and \" characters who are at the end and the beginning are the cause of the error in json but again not as removing.

Answer (score 1):

Its looks like `JSON` data, instead interfering into `JSON`, just convert `JSON` string to `NSData` and then into `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`

```
NSString *jsonString = @"[{\"CodRTA\":\"1\",\"MenssRTA\":\"messaje error\",\"Resp\":\"\"}]";
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:json];
```

Now if you do following NSLog statement

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[json firstObject] objectForKey:@"CodRTA"]);
```

Result would be another NSDictionary.

```
{
    CodRTA = 1;
    MenssRTA = messaje error;
    Resp = "";
}
```

Btw, I formatted your JSON response, its look like this,

[image]

Comment: I'm doing exactly that but the json is always null

Comment: I found the error and that the original string is @ "\" [{\ "CodRTA \": \ "1 \", \ "MessageRTA \": \ "information \", \ "Resp \": \ "\ "}] \" "and \" characters who are at the end and the beginning are the cause of the error but again not as removing.

Answer (score 0):

Someting like that

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
  NSString *str=@"[{\"CodRTA\":\"1\",\"MenssRTA\":\"messaje error\",\"Resp\":\"\"}]";
        NSString *filtered = [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

                               NSLog(@"filtrado: %@", filtered);
```